# Cordova: Custom Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

How can I customize Xcode -> Build Settings using Cordova? Since the files can be overwritten, I am trying to use Cordova to set the entire Xcode project (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#open-a-project-within-xcode).

How can I set Build Settings, specifically "Other Linker Flags" through Cordova?

Other Linker Flags:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaAsq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but you can set this in your build.json file:

```
    "ios": {
        "release": {
            ...
            "buildFlag": [
                "OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -Wl,-sectcreate,__RESTRICT,__restrict,/dev/null"
            ]
        },
```

This seems to work. Cordova doesn't document the ability to use existing variables like `$(OTHER_LDFLAGS)`, so this may not be reliable. But in the output, I see it passing my flags along with the default `-ObjC` flag.